# How to add vertical border between 2 of 3 columns in .views-view-grid

Tags: drupal, view, border

I'm sorta new at this Drupal thing, but I'm going to do my best to explain my predicament. I am editing a site that had a border around a grid. I've figured out how to turn off the border around my grid. I'm trying to show only 1 vertical line between columns 1&2 and 1 vertical line between columns 2&3. I would think I could just put a border on one side of 2 of the columns or create some rule that would put a vertical line down between the columns.

Either way, I don't know my CSS nearly well enough to make this happen.

Here is how my view looks now (with grid border off): [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnNVO.jpg

Here is my current style.css code for it:

```
    .views-view-grid td {
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    width: 33%;
    }

    .views-view-grid tr {
    border-left: 0px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 0px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
```

Any help, advice or direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done by giving a *border-right* to all *<td>* elements and then just removing it from the last one.

```
.views-view-grid td {
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Drupal will usually automatically put classes on first and last element in a list or something similar. You can use those classes to remove the border from the last element. I don't know how it behaves when using a grid, but since you're using views, you can also use a HTML list display. If you use *float:left* on your *<li>* elements, it will behave just like your screenshot.

If you want to keep the current settings, you can try using a pseudo-selector:

```
.views-view-grid td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```